# How do I get rid of b prefix and ' ' in a string variable

Tags: python-3.x

So, I'm trying to get a piece of code to run replay, between two variables based on a function, it gets the right variable, but when I send the final command it sends with b and ' ' which messes up the telnet command

```
import telnetlib

host = "192.168.1.13" #changes for each device
port = 9993 #specific for hyperdecks
timeout = 10

session = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port, timeout)

TCi = 1
TCo = 1
def In():
    global TCi
    session.write(b"transport info \n")
    by = session.read_until(b";00",.5)
    print(by)
    s = by.find(b"00:")
    TCi = by[s:s+11]
def Out():
    global TCo
    session.write(b"transport info \n")
    by = session.read_until(b";00",.5)
    print(by)
    s = by.find(b"00:")
    TCo = by[s:s+11]
def IOplay():
    IOtc = "playrange set: in: " + str(TCi) + " out: " + str(TCo) + " \n"
    print(IOtc.encode() )
    session.write(IOtc.encode() )
    speed = "play: speed: 2 \n"
    session.write(speed.encode() )
```

expected

`b"playrange set: in: 00:00:01;11 out: 00:00:03;10 \n"`

recieved

`b"playrange set: in: b'00:00:01;11' out: b'00:00:03;10' \n"`

I need to get rid of the prefixes fo the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to interpolate the bytestrings into another bytestring, do not mix them. Then at the end just decode the bytestring if you want a string:

```
>>> no = "Interpolate string and %s" % b
>>> no
"Interpolate string and b'bytes'"

>>> yes = b"Interpolate bytes and %s" % b
>>> yes
b'Interpolate bytes and bytes'

>>> yes.decode()
'Interpolate bytes and bytes'
```

So in your example code:

```
>>> TCi = b"1"
>>> TCo = b"2"
>>> IOtc = b"playrange set: in: %s out: %s\n" % (TCi, TCo)
>>> IOtc
b'playrange set: in: 1 out: 2\n'
```

And since you need a bytestring at the end to write to the telnet session, this way you wouldn't need to re encode your resulting string, use the bytestring as is instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just decode it to an utf-8 string, when you're printing it:

```
print(IOtc.encode().decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: The print is just an easy way to debug

Comment: Well, then you can just do `IOtc = IOtc.encode().decode("utf-8")`